# simple calculation in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

sorry I am new to react and I am trying to make a simple calculation and I really get lost

this is my code

```js
if (price_format.sale_price) {
  return (
    <View style={[styles.viewPrice, style && style]}>
      <Text colorSecondary style={[styleText, styles.textPriceSale]}>
        {price_format.regular_price}
      </Text>
      <Text medium style={[styleText, styles.textSale]}>
        {price_format.sale_price}
      </Text>
      {isPercentSale && (
        <Badge
          status="error"
          value={t('common:text_sale_percent', { percent: price_format.percent_sale })}
          containerStyle={styles.viewBadge}
          badgeStyle={styles.badge}
          textStyle={styles.textBadge}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );
}
```

so price_format.sale_price return the sale price of my products

but I want to show a different sale price on the app example

```js
price_format.sale_price - 10
```

tried this but it does not seem to work

```js
let newp = price_format.sale_price - 10;
<Text medium style={[styleText, styles.textSale]}>
  {newp}
</Text>
```

---

```js
console.log(this.price_format.sale_price);
```

display an error on app

```
undefined is not object
```

and

```js
console.log(price_format.sale_price);
```

show some of my products price in console

*** at the end i combined both answers to solve this

Comment: Are you doing the calculation just for the sake of displaying diff values to seem like diff products? Also, can you be more specific when you say "does not seems to work"? Is there any error in your console?

Comment: @DiogoSanto just for display not anything more, for example product sale price is 20 i want to display 10, it is different products with different sale prices

Comment: Just asking as if it is something you want just for the sake of being diff all around, I could advice using the `rand` call. If you are to use that variable, could you show me its declaration in your code as well, please? :)

Comment: sorry i have no idea, this is app is using woocommerce api. i thought it would be easy like php. {price_format.sale_price} is returning the product sale price just need to reduce 10 from the number that is geting

Comment: No problem! We just need to go to the bottom of the issue here, as it can be many things :P May I ask for you to do `console.log(price_format.sale_price);` as make sure it actually holds a value? If it does not display anything in your console, can you do `console.log(this.price_format.sale_price);` and check again for any displayed value in your console? We are trying to understand here if you are targeting your variable in its correct scope

Comment: thanks for your help, it return many products price

Comment: Ofc! We are here for each other if we are able to help! :D Do you mind updating your question with that information? It will help me visualise what you have in your end

Comment: console.log(this.price_format.sale_price); return error undefined in not an object

Comment: Hmmm, you say `price_format.sale_price` is returning your product prices. Can you try `console.log(parseFloat(price_format.sale_price) - 10);`? In case it is carrying the value as a string

Comment: console.log(parseFloat(price_format.sale_price) - 10);  return  LOG  NaN

Comment: Sorry, you will have to try and substitute when you attribute it to the variable as it will need to have a value when drawing the view. `let newp = parseFloat(price_format.sale_price) - 10;` I believe that is what the `LOG NaN` is informing here

Comment: yes i get NAN, seems to be the issue that output contain currency symbol and a point in price

Answer (score 0):

Just check this code below if it helps or not

```
if (price_format.sale_price) {

let regular_price = price_format.regular_price;
let sale_price = price_format.sale_price;
let new_price = sale_price - 10 ;

return (
  <View style={[styles.viewPrice, style && style]}>
    { regular_price ? 
      <Text colorSecondary style={[styleText, styles.textPriceSale]}>
        {regular_price}
      </Text> : 
      <Text>
        Regular price not found
      </Text>
    }
   { new_price ?
      <Text medium style={[styleText, styles.textSale]}>
        {new_price}
      </Text> : 
      <Text>
        New price not found
      </Text>
    }
    { isPercentSale ? 
      <Badge
        status="error"
        value={t('common:text_sale_percent', {percent: price_format.percent_sale})}
        containerStyle={styles.viewBadge}
        badgeStyle={styles.badge}
        textStyle={styles.textBadge}
      />
     : null }
  </View>
);
  }
else {
 return (
   <View>
      <Text>Price Not Found</Text>
   </View>
);
}
```

I put in there some logical statement just case of testing you can remove it after sort of testing. Let me know the status.

Comment: { sale_price ?
      <Text medium style={[styleText, styles.textSale]}>
        {sale_price}
      </Text> : 
      <Text>
        Sale price not found
      </Text>
    }

Comment: try to put sale price code to print its value @mrirox

Comment: { sale_price ? <Text medium style={[styleText, styles.textSale]}> {sale_price} </Text> : <Text> Sale price not found </Text> } return the price

Comment: will you show me the price for any one of item? means is it come along with any other symbols or anything?

Comment: ₪ 249.90, with shekel symbol

Comment: @mrirox It seems like you are getting string value so first seperate integer from string.

Comment: let new_price = sale_price.match(/\d+/g) - 10;

Comment: not only the currency symbole is causing the problem the point as well > output 5.00 ₪ if try static without .00 your code work match(/\d+/g)  but after i add the .00 to the 5 it does not work

Comment: let  new_price = parseFloat(sale_price.split(" ")[1]) - 5;

Comment: @mrirox did it work? If it works you should mark the answer as correct by clicking on the check mark near the score

Answer (score 0):

The issue with this seems to be how the content is being received. In JS, if you are holding a string within a variable things can get a bit weird. Let me explain:

```js
let shouldBeANumber = '10';
```

is different from

```js
let shouldBeANumber = 10;
```

The first is a string whilst the second is a Integer and they are used differently.
In your case:

```js
   let price_value = '$15.56';
```

Anything other than a number (with exception to the decimal marks) will be parsed as a string. This means if you try to sum something to it, you will actually have:

```js
let notANumber = "$15.56" + 10;
```

Would output `$15.5610`, because it is concatenating because it is holding a string.

With your react code, I believe you need to parse your prices before you do any mathematical interaction with them. For such, I would recommend a regex to extract only numbers (including if decimals):

```js
let EXTRACT_NUMBERS_REGEX = /[[\d]*[.]{0,2}[\d]+/g;
```

Use the above to extract the numbers from your price, cast it to float `parseFloat(extractedRegexNumberPriceHere)` (just in case) and then do what you gotta do!

Hope it helps!